# Filled area between four function, label axis in different position

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to fill area between my functions. It needs to be transparent to make axis visible. Second my question is: how to change the position of label of vertical axis?

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
% style
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=
    middle, xlabel={$\phi$}, ylabel={$\psi$}, axis equal }}
\begin{axis}[my style, minor tick num=2,blend group = soft light]
% drawing four functions
\addplot[name path=A,domain=0:1]{x-1};
\addplot[name path=B,domain=0:1]{-x+1 };
\addplot[name path=C,domain=-1:0]{x+1};
\addplot[name path=D,domain=-1:0]{-x-1};
% drawing rectangles
\fill[blue!40!white,rotate=45] (25,25) rectangle (175,175);
\fill[red!40!white] (25,25) rectangle (175,175);
```

I tried to draw rectangle but as you can see it doesn't rotate as I wanted. Is there any different way to achieve this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Setting option `compat` at least to value 1.11 (current version is 1.17) you can draw and fill the rectangle in one step:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}% <- added
% style
\pgfplotsset{
  my style/.style={
    axis lines=middle,
    axis equal,
    xlabel={$\phi$},
    ylabel={$\psi$}, 
    ylabel style=right,% <- added
    xmin=-1,xmax=1,% <- added
    ymin=-1,ymax=1,% <- added
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[my style, minor tick num=2,blend mode=soft light]
    \draw[fill=red!50!white](-1,0)--(0,-1)--(1,0)--(0,1)--cycle;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with the same result:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}% <- added
% style
\pgfplotsset{
  my style/.style={
    axis lines=middle,
    axis equal,
    xlabel={$\phi$},
    ylabel={$\psi$}, 
    ylabel style=right% <- added
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[my style, minor tick num=2,blend mode=soft light]
    \addplot[domain=0:1]{x-1};
    \addplot[domain=0:1]{-x+1 };
    \addplot[domain=-1:0]{x+1};
    \addplot[domain=-1:0]{-x-1};
    \fill[red!50!white](-1,0)--(0,-1)--(1,0)--(0,1)--cycle;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```